# Failed to execute goal net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.2:unpack due to API Incomatibility

Tags: maven, spring-roo, unpack

I'm new to Spring Roo as well as Maven. I was trying to setup a basic Google App Engine web application using Spring Roo. But when I run the tests - perform tests/mvn test - I get an error saying unable to run the goal Unpack due to API incomatibility.

Details:
gae.version: 1.6.1
gae-runtime: 0.9.2

Tried the same with 1.6.0 and 0.9.0 - still gives me the same error.

Exception:

```
    [INFO] --- maven-gae-plugin:0.9.2:unpack (default) @ project_x ---
    Feb 8, 2012 2:47:40 PM org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.Logs$JULSink warn
    WARNING: Error injecting: net.kindleit.gae.UnpackGoal
    java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type net.kindleit.gae.UnpackGoal not present
        at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:109)
        at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.NamedClass.load(NamedClass.java:45)
            ...
            ...
        ... 41 more
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 27.836s
    [INFO] Finished at: Wed Feb 08 14:47:40 IST 2012
    [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/12M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.2:unpack (default) on project project_x: Execution default of goal net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.2:unpack failed: Unable to load the mojo 'unpack' in the plugin 'net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.2' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: Bad version number in .class file
    [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] realm =    plugin>net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.2
    [ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
    [ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/myself/.m2/repository/net/kindleit/maven-gae-plugin/0.9.2/maven-gae-plugin-0.9.2.jar
    [ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/myself/.m2/repository/net/kindleit/gae-runtime/1.6.1/gae-runtime-1.6.1.pom
    ... 
    ..
```

I tried googling this issue, but didn't come across anyone facing this issue. I guess, I'm missing some dependency in the generated POM - but due to my inexperience I'm not able to figure out the exact cause.

Let me know, if I need to upload the generated pom.xml or any other details.

meanwhile, I'll continue to figure out what is causing the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an API incompatibility:

> due to an API incompatibility:
>   org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException:
>   Bad version number in .class file